# VIM destroys symbolic links under Windows

Tags: windows, vim, symbolic-link

It seems that when working with a file in **VIM** it primarily uses a backup version of the file then overwrites the original on save. This is a problem when using symbolic links under Windows (e.g. `mklink link_path target_path`) as it destroys the symbolic link.

Does anyone know a way around this? I've already seen this in the [FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/os_win32.html) which talks specifically to this issue but the recommended workaround doesn't work. Maybe it did at some point but not for Vim 7.3 (under Windows 7 x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [7.3.1182](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/vI8gjclL-48/3KJlK0iEjOkJ). Vim 7.4 is the first release on vim.org to include this patch (released 2013-08-10).

To support older versions of vim, you can use something like this in your vimrc:

```
" Writing files on Windows doesn't preserve file attributes seen via cygwin
" (presumably because the created backup copy didn't inherit them correctly).
if has('win32') && v:version < 704
    set backupcopy=yes
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Hum on windows, the symlink is moved to create the backup file. Then the corrections are written with the first name. (NB: The temp file is still linked to the original file)

They say that "The only way to fix this in the current version is not
   making a backup file, by `:set nobackup nowritebackup` "

Is that the workaround you were talking about? Because this is working on my vista.

EDIT: Of course, you won't have backups.

Comment: What happens when you use a hard link instead?

Comment: Works with hardlinks AND backup. I just had to remove the readonly flag.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on my machine: Windows 7 x64. When I save the file I always lose the symlink. In my vimrc I have: `set nobackup` and `set nowritebackup`.

Comment: I've just tested on a windows 7 x32. It works even better since I can do it with symlinks AND backup (and of course hardlinks). Vim version is 7.3.46.

Answer (score 2):

If you still need backups, you can use:

```
set bkc=yes
```

(why? read `:h bkc`) it solves the problem on Windows.

If the original file is read-only, you have to remove the read-only flag before opening the file. Alternatively while editing the file, you can remove the read-only flag, and run `:set modifiable` then save it.

There is an alternative using resolve() to resolve the path pointed to by the link. I use version7.3 and resolve() seems to fail to resolve links made with the `mklink` command on Windows):

> http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-make-e-path-completion-follow-symlinks-td1175347.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the backupcopy option can be nicer if you only have certain files or directories in which you expect to find symbolic links. For example, I use sym links to edit runtime files in my vim source code repository and see the changes reflected in my ~/vimfiles directory:

```
" for some reason, backupcopy=auto doesn't work on Windows to keep
" symbolic links. I use these in my vimfiles directory to override some
" runtime files which I really edit in the vim source repository.
autocmd BufWritePre ~/vimfiles/* set backupcopy=yes
autocmd BufWritePost ~/vimfiles/* set backupcopy&
```

Note that the default value of 'backupcopy' is SUPPOSED TO keep symbolic links when writing, according to the :help.

See http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/a85f18df1b543fec

Comment: The bug was fixed in 7.3.1182 (which I think is the same patch you linked) but Vim 7.4 is the first win32 release on vim.org to include this patch (released 2013-08-10).