# How to prevent a VIM file from becoming read-only when edited via a Windows symbolic link?

Tags: windows, vim, vimrc

I've set nobackup and nowritebackup per this question - [VIM destroys symbolic links under Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/193872/vim-destroys-symbolic-links-under-windows)

However, whenever I modify the file via the link, the target file is set to read-only.

How can I prevent the link target from becoming read-only?

Comment: Do symbolic links on Windows have an extension?

Comment: Is this symbolic link pointing to a file on a windows share?  or an NFS-connected drive?   Are the files linked to local files (same disk essentially)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug in VIM incorrectly interpreting file-attributes on Windows.

The bug is described in ['backupcopy' and Windows Vista symbolic links](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/qF8Y3xtUP-w/W1x7mZ4FrnkJ),
where a patch was developed to solve the problem.

I believe you will just have to wait until that patch finds its way to the release.
Your other options are to download the latest [VIM patch](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) (if later than your version)
or to compile your own,
and if the bug is still not fixed report it again to the VIM developers.